# consulta de un numero de una tabla

Tags: java, sql

Quiero hacer una función en java en la que de argumento recibe una cadena (de números o números y letras) y que este me consulte si en la tabla se encuentra esa cadena específica y en caso de que si exista me mande un mensaje.

yo tengo el siguiente planteamiento de la función

```
 public static String existe(String identificacion){
    String msg="";
    Connection cnConexion=Database.getConexion();
    PreparedStatement psBusca=null;
    ResultSet rBusca=null;

    String consultaNum = "SELECT nombre as numero from producto where id = identificacion";

    psBusca=cnConexion.prepareStatement(consultaNum);

    rBusca=psCodE.executeQuery();

    //if(cumple){ mensaje de que existe}
    //if( no cumple){ mensaje de que puede continuar}
    return msg;
}
```

No tengo idea de como trabajar una cadena en el SQL, ni como ejecutar el where por que me imagino que con esta sentencia tengo que hacer la consulta.

Si me pueden dar una mano les agradezco mucho.

Comment: ¿tienes la tabla ya definida?

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar más información sobre la base de datos y sobre cómo te comunicas con ella?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu duda es pasar la cadena a numero en java para posteriormente tratar ese numero como numero en sql se hace de la siguiente manera, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
String cadena="1";

int numero=Integer.parseInt(cadena);
```